# how to return a html String in springmvc

Tags: html, spring-mvc

I have spelled a html String in my controller and I just want display it in page as html,but it diplay just as a String not a html.
    response.setContentType("text/html"); 
    response.getWriter().println("1111");

It display on screen 1111,how can it looks like 1111 .

Forgive my english.
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Just store your response string in a Model and return a view. In the view (jsp), use the model data and print that string in an html format.

Example:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String prepare(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("foo", "bar");
    model.addAttribute("fruit", "apple");
    return "views/html"; //view name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resove it myself. Springmvc is right.what is wrong is when i save my string in database, it change my '<' to '＜' ,so the web brower can not recognize it correctly. so i use Stingutil.escape to decode it then use Stringutil.unescape to undecode.